# How search product with rtk query, react and material ui?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, rtk-query

I need to search for products and filter the results found. I'm using the https://fakestoreapi.com/

I created an input passing the typed value and the onchange to get the changes. Although, is not working. I created a function to filter the data but it didn't work.

**SearchInput.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'
import { Box, TextField, InputAdornment } from "@mui/material";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import { useGetAllProductsQuery } from '../../services/features/api/shopApiSlice';
import { SearchResult } from '../../components/Search';

export const SearchInput = () => {
    const [searchProduct, setSearchProduct] = useState("");
    const { data, error, isError, isLoading, isFetching } = useGetAllProductsQuery();
    const handleChangeSearch = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target
        setSearchProduct(value);
        console.log(value);
    };

    const filterProducts = () => {
        return data.filter((product) => {
            return product.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchProduct.toLowerCase());
        });
    }

    return (
        <Box
            component="form"
            noValidate
        >
            <TextField
                type="search"
                size='small'
                sx={{
                    width: "100%",
                }}
                id="pesquisar-produto"
                placeholder="Pesquisar"
                value={searchProduct}
                onChange={handleChangeSearch}
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="start">
                            <SearchIcon />
                        </InputAdornment>
                    )
                }}
            />
            <SearchResult filterProducts={filterProducts}/>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

To show the result I created another component, SearchResult.jsx.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

export const SearchResult = ({ filterProducts }) => {
    return (
        <Box>
            {filterProducts().map((product) => {
                return (
                    <Box key={product.id}>
                        <li>{product.title}</li>
                    </Box>
                );
            })}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

The following error appears in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at filterProducts (SearchInput.jsx:17:21)
    at SearchResult (index.jsx:7:14)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
The above error occurred in the <SearchResult> component:
```

PS: [Code github](https://github.com/paulinha-19/fake-shopping-cart)

[Demo](https://fake-store-on.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 1):

When the returned `data` value is undefined the code can't call any `filter` function. Without seeing your API slice and what the "GetAllProducts" endpoint returns, a decent guard is to provide a fallback value to filter from.

```
const filteredProducts = (data || []).filter((product) => {
  return product.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchProduct.toLowerCase());
});
```

```
<SearchResult filterProducts={filteredProducts} />
```

```
export const SearchResult = ({ filterProducts = [] }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      {filterProducts.map((product) => (
        <Box key={product.id}>
          <li>{product.title}</li>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Drew, the error in console it's not appared more. But, the search of product dont worked. It's not retorned the product searched.

Comment: @Begginer I think we'd need to see a bit more of the code that is making and processing the requests. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]? Think you could also create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://fake-store-on.netlify.app/ demo online

Comment: @Begginer I said sandbox, something where we can see the code ***and*** the demo running at the same time. This is so we can debug the code, not a website.

Comment: Already resolve the problem, thanks.